# Equivalent definition of convexity with $\theta \in (0,1)$ instead of $[0,1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, gateaux-derivative

We defined a functional  $\Phi: V \to \mathbb{R}$ ($V$ is a Banach space) to be convex if
$$ \tag{1}
\Phi((1 - \theta) v + \theta w) \le (1 - \theta) \Phi(v) + \theta \Phi(w) \quad \forall v,w \in V \ \forall \theta \in [0,1].
$$
Our lecturer casually added that instead it suffices that $(1)$ holds for all $\theta \in (0,1)$, which I will call $(2)$.

Obviously, $(1)$ implies $(2)$, but I am not sure if they are indeed equivalent.
**Does equivalence hold if $\Phi$ is continuous?**

The setting is the following: $\Phi$ will always be the potential of an operator $A: V \to V^*$, meaning $\Phi$ will be Gateaux-differentiable and 
$$
\langle A u, v \rangle
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\Phi(u + h v) - \Phi(u)}{h} \quad \forall u,v \in V
$$
We defined a map $F: X \to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces to be Gateaux differentiable if $$y \mapsto \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{\Phi(x + h y) - \Phi(x)}{h}$$ is well defined (as in the limit exists) linear and bounded (therefore continuous, right?).

Comment: This statement holds for all operators when $\theta=0$ or $\theta=1$ so they are indeed equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equivalence is always true because the inequality becomes  an equality when $\theta=0$ or $\theta =1$.

Comment: Oh, right. Do you why the definition is often writing as $(1)$ and not as $(2)$?

Comment: I don't know. I often write $0<\theta <1$. @ViktorGlombik

Answer (score 2):

When $\theta=1$, (1) gives
$$
\Phi(w) \le \Phi(w)
$$
which is trivially true, and similarly for $\theta=0$ so the edge cases don't matter really